# Detect if browser is capable to auto-hide address bar

Tags: javascript, css, mobile

**I do not intend to force a change on the browsers auto-hide-address-bar behaviour**

I only want to detect if the browser *will change it's viewports height on scroll / is capable of doing so*

Why?
Fixed `<img />` with `height: 100%` and `object-fit: cover` – Ugly flash when the address-bar is getting hidden.